# JS para transponer texto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Requiero una herramienta para estar [transponiendo](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/transponer) líneas e insertando entre columnas " OR " sin tener que estar accediendo a internet, por lo que estoy construyendo este `html` que incluye un `textarea` para ingresar el listado y unos botones para `reset`, `copiar` y realizar la función transponer y modificar el valor entre columnas.

Necesito ayuda para formar el script en `js` para la función de `transpose`

Ejemplo del texto que se ingresaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta sería el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al volver a presionar "TRANSPONER TEXTO" volver al punto anterior.

Tengo ya este fragmento de código pero no logro hacerlo funcionar dentro del archivo `html`. ¿Me podrían asesorar?.

```
$(function () {
    mkTool(
        'text-transpose',
        function (text) {
            text = text.replace("\r\n", "\n");
            var lines = text.split("\n");
            var delim = $('#text-transpose-delimiter').val();

            var transposed = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var line = lines[i];
                if (delim == ' ') {
                    var row = line.split(/\s+/g);
                }
                else {
                    var row = line.split(delim);
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                    if (transposed[j] == undefined) {
                        transposed[j] = [];
                    }
                    transposed[j].push(row[j]);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < transposed.length; i++) {
                transposed[i] = transposed[i].join(delim);
            }
            return transposed.join("\n");
        }
    );
});
```

Este es el `HTML` completo donde lo quiero incluir.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
html {
 box-sizing: inherit;
width: 800px;
padding-left: 30%;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 50%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {

  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #E3EFF0;
  /* Fallback for when there is no custom background color defined. */
box-sizing: inherit;
width: 800px;
padding-left: 10%;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 50%;
}


fieldset {
    background: #f8f8f8;
font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}
blockquote {
  quotes: "" "";
  padding: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-left: 3px solid #e74c3c;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
}
blockquote p {
  margin: 0;
}
blockquote cite {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

hr {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul, ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

ul {
  list-style: disc;
}

ol {
  list-style: decimal;
}

li > ul,
li > ol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Adhere to container width. */
}

figure {
  margin: 1em 0;
  /* Extra wide images within figure tags don't overflow the content area. */
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
}

th {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.site-footer table, .site-footer th, .site-footer td {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
.site-footer th {
  background: #222;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Forms
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}
button:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #222222;
}
button:active, button:focus,
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus {
  background: #222222;
}

textarea#text-transpose-text {
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 761px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 234px;
}

.th-readmore {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.th-readmore:hover {
  background: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.th-readmore:active,
.th-readmore:focus,
.th-readmore:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="range"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="color"],
textarea {
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px 5px;

}
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="range"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  color: #111;

}

select {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

  </style>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" TYPE="text/javascript">

<!-- Begin
  function copy3(){
document.extractor2.splitter2.focus()

document.extractor2.splitter2.select()

document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Text Copied");

}

function reset3(){
document.extractor2.splitter2.focus()

document.extractor2.splitter2.value=''



}
//  End -->


</SCRIPT>
</head>


<body>

<div class="posts-wrap th-grid-2" style="height: auto !important;">  


<!-- automatic size responsive -->

<form name="extractor2">
<fieldset class="titlebarcolor">
<h3><font class="titlefont"> Inserte Texto  </font></h3>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="titlebarcolor">
<textarea name="splitter2" rows="12" cols="80" id="text-transpose-text"></textarea>

        </fieldset></form>
        <fieldset class="maincolor"><input type="BUTTON" class="buton" value="Reset" onclick="reset3();">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="BUTTON" class="button2" value="Copiar" onclick="copy3();">  &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Transponder Texto" id="text-transpose-submit"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <span id="text-transpose-submit-undo" class="undo"><a href="#">(Deshacer)</a></span>
      Delimitador de Columnas: <input type="text" value=" OR " size="5" id="text-transpose-delimiter"> Por Defecto</fieldset>
        <div class="field">
    <div id="action-error" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); display: none;"></div>
    <div id="action-success" style="color:#00ff00;"></div>
  </div>


</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Trata de ser más específico con tu duda o el error que estás teniendo separando tu código y tus dudas específicas, si se puede replicando el error de manera clara y funcional en orden de aclararte o resolverte el error que estás teniendo, no creo que vayas a obtener mucha ayuda si lo que pides es que te elaboren el código por ti, saludos.

Comment: Hola Aldo, me preguntaba qué es transponder

Comment: En ingles transpose , una matriz transpuesta ya sea columnas o filas

Comment: No se termina de entender lo que necesitas, además sería bueno que además de decir que el código tiene problemas menciones cuales son esos problemas y coloques un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y un ejemplo de como esperas los datos de salida

Comment: Listo , comparto imágenes

Comment: Lo que requiero es transponder texto en horizontal e ingresando datos entre columnas

Comment: Te refieres a poner texto originalmente en vertical y luego en horizontal?, puedes usar la propiedad writing-mode y pues para insertar los OR usa algún método de cadenas.

Comment: La palabra que buscas es *transponer* o *trasponer*, en correcto castellano. Por otra parte lo que comenta @ElliotWilliamson es una forma de solucionar tu problema. Si lo que deseas es implementar tu propia solución, empieza por aclarar qué hace exactamente el método `mkTool()` y de qué forma pretendes que el mismo se integre en tu solución. Formas de resolver esto hay muchas, pero debes ser más específico. En qué parte tienes problema exactamente y si acaso hay un mensaje de error, ¿cuál?. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    function trans(texto,delimitador){
        // removemos los espacios al principio y al final con trim
        // replasamos los saltos de line o retorno de carro con el delimintador
        // y retornamos el texto ya editado
        return texto.trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ` ${delimitador} `);
    }
    
    let transpose = document.querySelector("#text-transpose-submit");

    transpose.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        // previene el comportamiento por defecto
        e.preventDefault();

        let texto = document.querySelector("#text-transpose-text").value;
        let delimitador = document.querySelector("#text-transpose-delimiter").value;
        document.querySelector("#text-transpose-text").value = trans(texto,delimitador);
    })
```

```html
<div class="posts-wrap th-grid-2" style="height: auto !important;">  


<!-- automatic size responsive -->

<form name="extractor2">
<fieldset class="titlebarcolor">
<h3><font class="titlefont"> Inserte Texto  </font></h3>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="titlebarcolor">
<textarea name="splitter2" rows="12" cols="80" id="text-transpose-text"></textarea>

        </fieldset></form>
        <fieldset class="maincolor"><input type="BUTTON" class="buton" value="Reset" onclick="reset3();">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="BUTTON" class="button2" value="Copiar" onclick="copy3();">  &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Transponder Texto" id="text-transpose-submit"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <span id="text-transpose-submit-undo" class="undo"><a href="#">(Deshacer)</a></span>
      Delimitador de Columnas: <input type="text" value=" OR " size="5" id="text-transpose-delimiter"> Por Defecto</fieldset>
        <div class="field">
    <div id="action-error" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); display: none;"></div>
    <div id="action-success" style="color:#00ff00;"></div>
  </div>


</div>
```